# getDescription in the slide down panel

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, ce-1.9.0.1, jquery

I am trying to display the description for each product in the slide down panel. I am using a slider to display product images where I have a on hover buttons first one adds the product to basket and the second one triggers the slide down panel. It displays random products description not the one I click on.

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
 <?php  $categoryId = 4; // this is the category holding your products  
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addCategoryFilter($category);
 $products->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                              'image',
                              'name',
                              'description',
                             'short_description',
     'sku',
     'asin'
              ))
              ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                             Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                          Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
              )); 

 //$products->load();
 foreach ($products as $product)  { 
 ?>
 <div class="item">
 <img  class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product); ?>" alt="img" />
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__() ?>" 
 class="addp" onclick="setLocation
 ('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>')">
 <span><span><?php echo $this->__() ?></span></span></button>
   <button type="button" class="info" data-target='t1'>
   <?php

  $description = $product->getDescription();

  ?>
  </button>

 </div>  
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</div>

 <div class="toggles" data-target='t1'>
  <p> <?php echo $description; ?> </p>  
 </div>
```

I would like to get Description for each products I click on no the same one for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to echo description inside the loop. you are echo it outside the so it is showing last description.

```
     $description='';

         foreach ($products as $product)  { 
             ?>
             <div class="item">
             <img  class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product); ?>" alt="img" />
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__() ?>" 
             class="addp" onclick="setLocation
             ('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>')">
             <span><span><?php echo $this->__() ?></span></span></button>
               <button type="button" class="info" data-target='t<?php echo $product->getId() ?>'>
               <?php

              $description .= $product->getDescription().'<br />';

              ?>
              </button>

             </div> 


         <?php
          }
         ?>
        </div>

   <?php  foreach ($products as $product)  { ?>
    <div class="toggles" data-target='t<?php echo $product->getid()?>'>
          <p> <?php echo  $product->getDescription(); ?> </p>

         </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When I do that the whole slider messes up , as there is only 1 product in the slider and the rest of the products are underneath it. However they display correct description which is a good thing

Comment: check the update answer...

Comment: The latest edit displays all of the product descriptions at once , when I click the button of the certain product in the dropdown there are all of the descriptions

Comment: update the answer follow that